How to derive $\partial^{\nu}F^{\mu\alpha} + \partial^{\alpha}F^{\nu\mu} + \partial^{\mu}F^{\alpha\nu}=0$ for the Electromagnetic field tensor?
The problem says to show that
$$\partial_{[\mu}F_{\alpha\nu]}=F^{\mu\alpha, \nu} + F^{\nu\mu,\alpha} + F^{\alpha\nu,\mu}=0$$ stems from Maxwell equations.
I haven't been able to find this anywhere on the internet and Introduction to Electrodynamics by Griffiths doesn't cover it. Every webpage or PDF I encounter just says that the homogeneous Maxwell equations given by
$$\partial_\mu G^{\mu\nu} = 0$$
can be written in terms of $F^{\mu\nu}$ as
$$\partial^{\nu}F^{\mu\alpha} + \partial^{\alpha}F^{\nu\mu} + \partial^{\mu}F^{\alpha\nu}=0.$$
The was only able to find one PDF that said I needed to contract the Maxwell equations with $\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\rho}$ and untangling the following equation:
$$\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\rho}\partial^{\chi}G_{\chi\rho}=\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\rho}\partial^{\chi}\epsilon^{\chi\rho\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}.$$
I'm new to tensor algebra and have no clue how to start at all. Any help would be appreciated.

That equation is just a rewrite of Maxwell's equations without sources (the Gauss law of magnetism and the Faraday law) in four-tensor notation. So start with those Maxwell's equations, write them in cartesian components of fields $\mathbf E,\mathbf B$ and compare to equations you get when you express $\partial_{[\mu} F_{\alpha \nu]}$ in terms of those same cartesian components.

Try to have a look here https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/relativity/special/em_4d.html

@JánLalinský I was able to derive the equations for every index just like Archisman Panigrahi said, but I'm not sure if that is what my professor expects as a solution (probably expects something more formal). I'm still a bit puzzled by what you want me to try.

I don't know what you're puzzled by. You want to derive the four-tensor way of writing the Maxwell equations. I assume you know the standard way of writing them using 3-vectors $\mathbf E,\mathbf B$. You can derive the four-tensor equations by showing from definition of $F$  in terms of 6 components of $\mathbf E,\mathbf B$ that they lead to the same equations for all 6 components as the standard 3-vector equations.

Write down $\partial_\mu G^{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2}{\epsilon^{\mu \nu \alpha \beta}\partial_\mu F_{\alpha\beta}}$.
Now, fix the free index $\nu$ (to be either of 0, 1, 2, 3), and write down all non-zero terms by expanding the Einstein summation in the indices $\alpha, \beta, \mu$.
You will recover the Bianchi identity for the three indices except the one you fixed for $\nu$.
Now repeat for each value of $\nu$.
